# How to use cte?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple construction with cte like:

```
;WITH Base_cte AS 
    (
        SELECT
        FROM
        WHERE
    )

SELECT
FROM
   (
       SELECT
       FROM Base_cte
       WHERE
    )

SELECT
FROM Base_cte
WHERE
```

which returns for the second select with cte:

> Invalid object name 'Base_cte'.

I have no idea why it can not recognize the cte for the second time. The code is too large to paste here, but fair simple basically I think I must missing something fundamental.
Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: You can only use the CTE in the select immediately following the CTE definition. If you want to use it in other queries, your first query could insert the data into a temp table, for example.

Comment: wrap your second select statement to other CTE

Comment: Common table *expressions* are only part of the statement they're in. Your second query is logically a new statement, in which `Base_cte` is not defined. Mixing CTEs and subqueries looks clumsy, by the way: you can do `WITH X AS (...), Y AS (... FROM X), Z AS (... FROM Y) SELECT ... FROM Z` instead, building up the queries as you go along.

Comment: In that case, would not be better to use TempTable instead of CTE?

Comment: Whether to use a temp table or a CTE depends greatly on the performance characteristics of your quer(ies) and the size of the intermediate results. Sometimes a temp table is better, sometimes a CTE is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use this format

```
;WITH Base_cte AS 
    (
        SELECT
        FROM
        WHERE
    )
,CTE1 AS
(
       SELECT
       FROM Base_cte
       WHERE
)
SELECT * FROM CTE1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the 2nd CTE? Why not:

```
;with base_cte as
(
    select
    from
    where
)

select *
from base_cte
join
where
```